# Convert Category to Numerical Labels in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A1','B1','C1','D1'],'Category':['A','A','C','B']})
df
    Item    Category
0   A1      A
1   B1      A
2   C1      C
3   D1      B
```

I would like to manually cluster them i.e. Category A will belong to Cluster 1, C will belong to 2, B will belong to 3, etc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['A1','B1','C1','D1'],'Category':['A','A','C','B'], 'Label':['1','1','2','3']})
df

    Item    Category    Label
0   A1      A           1
1   B1      A           1
2   C1      C           2
3   D1      B           3
```

I am thinking of doing Label Encoding, are there any other methods that I can try? What is the appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Label'] = pd.factorize(df['Category'])[0] + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

With `groupby`:

```
df["Cluster"] = df.groupby("Category", sort=False).ngroup()+1

>>> df
  Item Category  Cluster
0   A1        A        1
1   B1        A        1
2   C1        C        2
3   D1        B        3
```